# Difference between 'range' tags; discussion about wireless range/signal tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tags

We have a total of 27 [range](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/range) questions on SU. Of these, **15** refer to *wireless-range* and **12** to *data-range*.

My thought is to split these up into [wireless-range](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-range) and [data-range](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/data-range) and have the [range](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/range) be a synonym or burninated.

---

Per Daniel Beck below:

1. [signal-strength](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/signal-strength) has **14** questions
2. [wireless-signal-booster](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-signal-booster) has **2** questions
3. [wireless-strength](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-strength) has **1** question.
4. These should all be synonyms or merged/burninated into [wireless-range](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-range)

I'm careful of bringing these toward [wireless-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-networking) because some of these questions are talking about wireless range of devices that are **not** networking devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synonym should go to the one that is used more often, in this case [wireless-range](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-range).

Therefore I'd say:

- Create those tags by splitting up
- Create the synonym [range](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/range) → [wireless-range](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-range).

Comment: I can't say I disagree with the logic.

Comment: There's also `wireless-strength`, `signal-strength` and `wireless-signal-booster`. More cleanup should probably be done.

Comment: @DanielBeck Good point, added to my initial question

Comment: @Raystafarian You forgot one.

Comment: @DanielBeck fixed!